# Storing a binary hash value in a Django model field

Tags: python, django, encoding, django-models, binary-data

I have a twenty byte hex hash that I would like to store in a django model. 
If I use a text field, it's interpreted as unicode and it comes back garbled.

Currently I'm encoding it and decoding it, which really clutters up the code,
because I have to be able to filter by it.

```
def get_changeset(self):
    return bin(self._changeset)

def set_changeset(self, value):
    self._changeset = hex(value)

changeset = property(get_changeset, set_changeset)
```

Here's an example for filtering

```
Change.objects.get(_changeset=hex(ctx.node()))
```

This is the approach that was recommended by a django developer, but I'm really struggling to come to terms with the fact that it's this ugly to just store twenty bytes.

Maybe I'm too much of a purist, but ideally I would be able to write

```
Change.objects.get(changeset=ctx.node())
```

The properties allow me to write:

```
change.changeset = ctx.node()
```

So that's as good as I can ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming if you were writing raw SQL you'd be using a Postgres bytea or a MySQL VARBINARY. There's a [ticket with a patch](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2417) (marked "needs testing") that purportedly makes a field like this (Ticket 2417: Support for binary type fields (aka: bytea in postgres and VARBINARY in mysql)).

Otherwise, you could probably try your hand at writing a [custom field type](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/).

Comment: n.b. despite this answer being four years old, BinaryField isn't in the latest release of Django (1.5) but is in the current development version.

Comment: It's now available as `BinaryField` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield

Answer (score 4):

Starting with 1.6, Django has [`BinaryField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield) allowing to store raw binary data. However, for hashes and other values up to 128 bits it's more efficient (at least with the PostgreSQL backend) to use [`UUIDField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) available in Django 1.8+.

Comment: BinaryField does not support query, which is sad

Answer (score 3):

"I have a twenty byte hex hash that I would like to store in a django model."

Django does this.  They use hex digests, which are -- technically -- strings.  Not bytes.

Do not use `someHash.digest()` -- you get bytes, which you cannot easily store.

Use `someHash.hexdigest()` -- you get a string, which you can easily store.

**Edit** -- The code is nearly identical.

See http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html

Comment: Using a different encoding doesn't make the code any cleaner. If I still have to encode and decode I haven't gained anything.

Comment: Sorry if my answer confused you.  I've revised it.  digest() and hexdigest() are nearly identical.  Except you can persist hexdigest().  You can't easily persist digest().

Answer (score 2):

You could also write your own custom [Model Manager](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#topics-db-managers) that does the escaping and unescaping for you.

Answer (score 1):

If this issue is still of interest, Disqus' `django-bitfield` fits the bill:

https://github.com/disqus/django-bitfield

... the example code on GitHub is a little confusing at first w/r/t the modules' actual function, because of the asinine variable names -- generally I am hardly the sort of person with either the wherewithal or the high ground to take someone elses' goofy identifiers to task... but `flaggy_foo`?? Srsly, U guys.

If that project isn't to your taste, and you're on Postgres, you have a lot of excellent options as many people have written and released code for an assortment of Django fields that take advantage of Postgres' native type. Here's an `hstore` model field:

https://github.com/jordanm/django-hstore -- I have used this and it works well.

Here's a full-text search implementation that uses Postgres' termvector types:

https://github.com/aino/django-pgindex

And while I cannot vouch for this specific project, there are Django `bytea` fields as well:

https://github.com/aino/django-arrayfields

Comment: Personally I store all my hex hashes as text, but I never have had to create indexes on any of them so seek performance hasn't been an issue  (I take it you are facing something like that)