# Postgres' text column doesn't like my zlib compressed data

Tags: sql, postgresql, compression, zlib

Is there a better data type to be using to store a zlib compressed string in Postgresql?

Comment: For PostgreSQL automatic compression (by TOAST), see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3801416/287948

Answer (score 8):

Use [bytea](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/datatype-binary.html) "The bytea data type allows storage of binary strings"

Comment: Interesting. Any idea what this would be in Django? Meaning what Django field type would yield this type in Postgres?

Comment: Apparently django doesn't support bytea directly - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517349/binaryfields-in-django-models , You could e.g. base64 encode your data and continue to use a text field - though you'd lose some of the benefit of compression

Comment: See [`BinaryField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield).

Answer (score 4):

Use a [bytea](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/datatype-binary.html). Zip compressed data is not a text.

Comment: Citing sources last updated 8 years ago when up to date and authoritative sources exist is probably more confusing than helpful.

Comment: `bytea` , as by other answer, is what corresponds, in Postgresql, to the BLOB concept.